# MCMC Monte Carlo aspect to the picture

Tags: python, markov-chain-montecarlo

I found a problem online about some particles probability in 2 locations. It's described using a Markov matrix like this  {0.6,0.2}{0.4,0.8}  After so many trials the equilibrium probability is 1/3 and 2/3.

I wanted to do this with some Monte carol method, so I found someones code, and changed it around so it gave me this [software picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yox8l.png). Is there any Monte Carol aspect to this picture. Is it the zig-zag lines that converge to the probability, or is it something else. I'm a EE major and don't really know statistics very well, so sorry for the informal language. I know you can take the ending pints of either position a or b and plot them on a histogram for something like a normal distribution. Here is some of the code.`states.append(np.random.choice((0,1,3), p=transition_matrix[states[-1]]))` Is the Monte Carlo part of it just this random.choice part of the code or is there more to it. `